# What is the correct syntax for echoing i in list (integer) bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to iterate through a list of numbers and (treating them as integers) put any numbers between the first search and the second search into a separate list.

I've tried a range of things including using round brackets, using quotes, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
first_search_item=3
second_search_item=6
lib=''
jim='1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
for i in jim;
do
  if [[ ${first_search_item} -le ${i} ]] && [[ ${i} -ge ${second_search_item} ]] ;
  then
    lib+=($i)
    echo $i
  fi
done
echo $lib
exit 0
```

The `lib` should be `3 4 5 6`, but I keep getting syntax errors.

This time, the syntax error is :

```
error token is "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

Comment: `for i in jim` -> `for i in ${jim}` and the `-ge` should be `-le`.

Comment: Multiple problems. Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `lib+="${i}\n"` or `lib+="${i} "`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace line 6:

```
for i in jim;
```

with this:

```
for i in $jim;
```

That will fix your problem.
And I recommend you this Shell Style Guide: https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html